# Does CORS affects localStorage?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, local-storage, cors

Searched everywhere and didn't find straight answer.
Does CORS make cross-(sub)domain localStorage sharing possible or not?
And how about on IE8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot directly access another origin's storage, regardless of CORS settings.

You could however have a remote AJAX service that could store your settings on the remote domain.

e.g. Say your main website `www.maindomain.com` returns header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.subsite.com` for its AJAX requests.

Then your other website `www.subsite.com` can make an AJAX request to e.g. `https://www.maindomain.com/storage` to retrieve or to save details cross-origin. The local storage for `www.maindomain.com` can be returned as a JSON object in the response for `www.subsite.com` to use.

Comment: I was hoping I could use it as a event dispatcher across windows with different sub-domains, but thanks for the definitive 'No'. I guess it's cookies and postMessage for me.